# prepareForSegue UICollectionView not working (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, uicollectionview, segue

I’ve tried to push segue by using UICollectionView (show image form MasterView to DeatilView) but is not working.  Xcode also doesn’t show any error message. What’s wrong with my code. I need some advice.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

     if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
      if let indexPath = self.collectionView?.indexPathForCell(sender as! UICollectionViewCell) {
         let detailVC = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailMenuViewController
             detailVC.picFood = self.collection[indexPath.row]
```

- collection is empty array get data form json
- [title = self.nameFood.title],  it is  working in DetailMenuViewController.swift but not image on code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `UICollecitonViewDelegate`

```
func collectionView(collection: UICollectionView, selectedItemIndex: NSIndexPath) 
{
   self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetail", sender: self)
}
```

After that add

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
          if let indexPath = self.collectionView?.indexPathForCell(sender as! UICollectionViewCell) {
             let detailVC = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailMenuViewController
                 detailVC.picFood = self.collection[indexPath.row]
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get ambiguous reference to member collectionView from `self.collectionView?.indexPathForCell(sender as! UICollectionViewCell)`. Is there an alternate solution to this?